# Modificar un atributo personalizado desde jquery

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estoy enviando datos desde mi base de datos con ajax y jquery a un modal en html y quisiera que un dato aparezca en un atributo personalizado de mi button,
lo estoy tratando de enviar de esta forma:

```
$( "#btn111" ).attr("idevl":(respuesta["id_entrenado"]));
```

Pero me da errores,
Este es mi codigo jquery desde mi ajax

```
 $(".js-verEvalFecha").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("identrenado");

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("identrenado", id);

    $.ajax({        
        url: "view/public/ajax/entrenados.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            
            success: function (respuesta) { 
                var valor1 = respuesta["finicio"];
                var valor2 = respuesta["ffin"];
                
                $("#verIdentrenado").val(respuesta["id_entrenado"]);   
                $("#verFinicio").val(respuesta["finicio"]);  
                
                $( "#btn111" ).attr("idevl":(respuesta["id_entrenado"]));
                

                if(valor2 !=null){
                    $("#verFinicio").prop("disabled", true);  
                  } else{
                    $("#verFinicio").prop("disabled", false);
                  };
                $("#verFfin").val(respuesta["ffin"]);
                if(valor1 !=null){
                    $("#verFfin").prop("disabled", true);  
                  } else{
                    $("#verFfin").prop("disabled", false);
                  };
                $("#modalAgregarEvaluacion").modal("show");   
           
        }
    })
})
```

Y este es el codigo html

```
 <div class="form-group col-lg-2" style="padding-top: 29px;">
 <button id="btnidevl" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnidevl" idevl="" >Agregar</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas atributos ya definidos (por ejemplo `value` si es un solo dato) o bien atributos `data-` si quisieras guardar varios valores.

Comment: De hecho, deberias usar [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) como dice @A.Cedano. Ya que para eso fue creado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value), la sintaxis para asignar un valor a un atributo es esta:

```
.attr( attributeName, value )
```

Entonces, si quieres asignar un atributo personalizado al botón sería así:

```
$( "#btn111" ).attr("idevl", respuesta['id_entrenado']);
```

No obstante, en lugar de optar por un atributo personalizado, es recomendable usar atributos ya definidos.

Por ejemplo, para un solo valor, podrías usar el atributo `value` del botón, el cual es un atributo definido por el estándar HTML. Una de las ventajas es que dicho atributo se enviaría con el formulario en caso de tener el botón en un formulario. Aparte de eso, puedes asignar/obtener su valor con métodos propios (`val()` en el caso de jQuery, o `value` en el caso de Javascript puro).

En el caso de más de un dato, podrías usar los [atributos `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). En el caso de jQuery podrías asignar un objeto completo mediante el método [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) y luego obtener ese objeto completo con el mismo método, o bien obtener datos individuales mediante el uso de `data('clave')`, como veremos en el ejemplo.

```js
/*Lo creamos a mano para la prueba*/
let respuesta={id_entrenado: 45, nombre: 'Pedro', apellido: 'Pérez'};

/*Referencia al botón*/
var oneButton=$('#btnidevl');

/*Personalizado*/
oneButton.attr('idevl',respuesta['id_entrenado']);
console.log(oneButton.attr('idevl'));

/*Value*/
oneButton.val(respuesta['id_entrenado']);
console.log(oneButton.val());

/*Atributos data-* OTRO nivel*/

/*Seteamos un objeto completo*/
oneButton.data(respuesta);

/*Lo mostramos completo*/
console.log(oneButton.data());

/*O por cada clave*/
console.log(oneButton.data('id_entrenado'));
console.log(oneButton.data('nombre'));
console.log(oneButton.data('apellido'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-lg-2" style="padding-top: 29px;">
 <button id="btnidevl" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btnidevl" >Agregar</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis correcta para asignar un atributo es:

```
jQuery("selector").attr("atributo", "valor a asignar");
```

En tu caso sería:

```
$( "#btn111" ).attr("idevl", respuesta['id_entrenado']);
```

La sintaxis con : se utiliza cuando quieres asignar más de un atributo a la vez en la misma sentencia, además no llevaría comillas en el nombre del atributo, puesto que se pasarían los parámetros como si fuesen un objeto, por ejemplo:

```
$( "#btn111" ).attr({
    idev1: respuesta['id_entrenado'],
    name: "nuevo name"
    });
```